# Verifying answers for current through each resistor question

Tags: circuit-analysis, current, resistors, kirchhoffs-laws

I found this question and would like to know whether my solution is correct.

I need to work out the current through each one of these resistors.
[image]

I got the following values for the current:

- I1 = 8.75 A
- I2 = 3.5 A
- I3 = 3.5 A
- I4 = 5.25 A
- I5 = 7 A

I couldn't find this question and it's solution anywhere, so I am not sure whether I have done this correctly. If someone could check this for me that would be brilliant.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome! Did you try to simulate it to get the correct answer?

Comment: Thanks, yh I put the values back in to the equations I got from kirchhoff's 1st law, and they seemed to check out. But I am still very new to this and would like to know for sure whether I arrived at the correct answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no asker try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answers for current flows are incorrect: -

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, what tool did you use to generate this?

Comment: Micro-cap 12 (a free simulator).

Comment: Thanks, I figured what I did wrong as well, appreciate the help a lot.